# Find the regular points.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is a power series, i.e., $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_nz^n$, and this function is define in $B(0,R)$, where $ 0 < R < \infty <$ and $R$ is the convergence radius.

We say $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, $|z_0| = R$ is a regular point of $f$ if exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that there is $g$ analytic in $B(z_0,\epsilon)$ and $g|_{B(0,R)} = f$

For example, $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^{n}z^{2n}$. In this case $R = 1$, and $g(z) = \frac{1}{1 + z^2}$ if $|z| < 1$, so $g$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}-\{\pm i\}$, so every point of $\mathbb{S} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}-\{ \pm i\}$ is regular of $f$.

Now, let $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} z^{n!} = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_nz^n$, where $a_n = 1$ if n = k!, for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ a_n = 0$, in the others cases. The $R$ is $1$ again, I've tried show that there isn't regular point of $f$, but I don't know how, because in the first case there's a candidate function and this case I don't see any possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Your $f(z):=\sum_{n\geq1}z^{n!}$ is a standard example in complex analysis. This function can indeed not be continued to points outside the unit circle $S^1$ anywhere.

*Proof.* Consider a point $\zeta:=e^{2\pi i p/q}\in S^1$ with rational argument modulo $2\pi$.  When $z=r\zeta$, $0<r<1$, then $z^{n!}=r^{n!}$ for all $n\geq q$. It follows that
$$\left|\sum_{n=q}^\infty z^{n!}\right|=\sum_{n=q}^\infty r^{n!}\to\infty\qquad(r\to 1-)\ .$$
This shows that $f$ as defined cannot be continued continuously to the point $\zeta$. Now such points $\zeta$ are dense in $S^1$. It follows that there cannot be an $e^{i\alpha}\in S^1$ such that an extension of $f$ would be analytic in a full neighborhood of $e^{i\alpha}$.